# Can I have win32 C checkboxes in a listbox control?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have the following dialog:

```
IDD_REMINDERS DIALOGEX 20, 20, 102, 166
STYLE DS_SETFONT | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
FONT 7, "Small Fonts", 0, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
    LISTBOX         IDC_REMINDERS_LIST, 1,12,100,152, LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE | LBS_HASSTRINGS | LBS_USETABSTOPS | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | LBS_DISABLENOSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    PUSHBUTTON      "×",IDC_CLOSE,90,-1,12,11,WS_GROUP | NOT WS_TABSTOP
    LTEXT           "...", IDC_REMINDERS_CAP, 1,1,75,8
    PUSHBUTTON      "+", IDC_REMINDERS_NEW, 78,-1,12,11, WS_GROUP | NOT WS_TABSTOP
END
```

In this dialog I'd like to display checkboxes on the right side.

I was under the impression that calling the following code should add checkboxes to the listbox:

```
ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyleEx(hWndListView, LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES, LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES);
```

Though, I now suspect I may be mixing up listboxes and listviews. Either way, I tried the same ListView_SetExtended call on a listview with the following code in the RC:

```
CONTROL         "",IDC_KEYS,"SysListView32", LVS_REPORT | LVS_SINGLESEL | LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS | LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LVS_OWNERDATA | LVS_NOCOLUMNHEADER | WS_TABSTOP,4,64,250,136
```

Sadly, this listview refused to show checkboxes as well.

Is it possible to have checkboxes in a listbox? (Without going ahead and drawing them yourself. Which will work fine short term, but seems more of a hassle in terms of longer term OS compatibility.)

Can this work if the listbox is set to "owner draw"? (I'm using that due to custom text coloring.)

Comment: [LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774732.aspx) is indeed only available to [List View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774737.aspx) controls. I don't know if this is compatible with owner-drawing, but if it is, you are responsible for rendering the checkboxes yourself. In the standard list view control they are implemented through state images.

Comment: I feared as much. Would it by any chance be possible to grab the system's original icons for checkboxes so I may draw those directly? (e.g. xp, w7, w8, w10 have different looking checkboxes, and they are stored as an image or icon in the OS) 
e.g.: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Or would have have to dig into offscreen drawing of an actual checkbox and then copy that to the DC?

Comment: Update: workaround "DrawThemeBackground" with theme "BUTTON".